# How to update spring property value from Java GUI data?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, user-interface

I have Spring context in src/main/resources

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
    class="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource">
    <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="databaseName" value="bookcompany"/>
    <property name="user" value="thisadmin"/>
    <property name="password" value="thisadmin"/>
</bean>
```

I want to update the "value" of each property value from Java swing GUI

***screenshoot*** : [Java Swing GUI for select database properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nsrc.png)

This is my Java GUI code:

```
private void connectButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
 String serverNew = serverName.getText();
 String databaseNew = databaseName.getText();
 String dbUsernameNew = databaseName.getText();
 String dbPasswordNew = databasePassword.getText();  

 //???
}
```

Is it possible to update property value of my spring-context using data from java GUI??
Please help..

Comment: as i understand it you would have to read the file and write the content there. there might be a library for that but i am not sure

Comment: thanks,, but what kind of library is it?

Comment: as i said before i am not sure if there is one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, I use the Properties file to store property values. Then my Spring context file uses that properties file.

First, I update Spring context file to this :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:./jdbc.properties" />
<bean id="dataSource" 
    class="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"> 
    <property name="serverName" value="${db.server}"/>
    <property name="databaseName" value="${db.database}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>
```

I update my Java code :

```
String serverNew = serverName.getText();
String databaseNew = databaseName.getText();
String dbUsernameNew = databaseName.getText();
String dbPasswordNew = databasePassword.getText();  

Properties props = new Properties();
File f = new File("./jdbc.properties");
if (f.exists()) {
    props.load(new FileReader(f)); 
    props.setProperty("db.host", serverNew);
    props.setProperty("db.database", databaseNew);
    props.setProperty("db.username", dbUsernameNew);
    props.setProperty("db.password", dbPasswordNew);
    f.createNewFile(); 
} 

out = new FileOutputStream(f);
props.store(out, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change those values if you create the object with `@Bean` and use `@ComponentScan`, but I am not sure if you can change the database connection parameters dynamically.

One thing you can do is to create a needed bean or object yourself after you have the values from GUI by extending `PersistenceUnitInfo` if you want a database connection, for example.